# How does contains in HashSet in Java run in O(1) time?

Tags: java

Is it only O(1) when there are no collision. Im talking about a hash table that has Linked Lists in each slot to hold the values.

Comment: The dictionary lookup is obviously constant time.  The collision lookup can be made small and essentially constant by using a decent hash function with enough slots.

Answer (score 1):

The average number of collisions is O(1), and if your hash function is essentially random you can prove that it's extremely improbable that there are many collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is O(1) if you have unique hash for keys and `LinkedList` or Binary Tree has only one item,

With Java 7 collision resolves to binary tree instead of LinkedList so it is not O(N) for collision

Comment: It is *1* under those circumstances. It is *O(1)* under all non-degenerate circumstances.

Comment: @EJP o(1) if you have hashcode  generator generating static value (for example: 1) ?

Comment: OK, under all non-degenerate circumstances.